# Is there a method in Pyspark equivalent to SQL's MSCK REPAIR TABLE

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark, nosql

In SQL there is:

```
REFRESH TABLE table_name
```

and in pyspark the equivalent is:

```
spark.refreshTable(table_name)
```

So, what would be the Pyspark's equivalent to:

```
MSCK REPAIR TABLE table_name
```

Comment: `spark.sql('MSCK REPAIR TABLE table_name')`

Comment: I know you can execute sql through spark.sql(), but that was not my question. I want to know a pyspark function exclusive for that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

refreshTable is integrated with spark session [catalog](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/sql/catalog.py).

as steven suggested, you can go with `spark.sql('MSCK REPAIR TABLE table_name')`

There is something called `recoverPartitions` (Only works with a partitioned table, and not a view) in the above link. I believe this is aliased version of  `msck repair table`. you can go ahead and try this..

see this [ddl.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/command/ddl.scala#L570) seems like its equalent by documentation.
example usage :

```
spark.catalog.recoverPartitions(tableName)
```

Comment: I think that recoverPartitions is what I am looking for. Will test it and come back later to confirm.

Comment: @Ram Ghadiyaram could you please throw some more light on recoverPartitions.. how does it works and is it available with pyspark

Comment: @vikrantrana yes it is available with pyspark. Just follow the link of the catalog doc in the answer.

Comment: @vikrantrana you just need to get your context and its catalog, In my case I used Spark Context: spark.catalog.recoverPartitions()